# Laravel 5.8 With layout variables reset password mail don't work

Tags: php, laravel-5.8

I am using `Laravel 5.8` default auth system. I have layout file where i have variables from category model and controller. I needed to merge this layout file with auth system blades. So far login and register works fine. I added in `LoginController`:

```
    public function showLoginForm(){

      $categories = Category::all();
      return view('auth.login', compact('categories'));
    }
```

Also i added same code in RegisterController in method "showRegistrationForm".

Next is "forgotPasswordController" and here i start to get errors. I added same code in method "showLinkRequestForm" and form is showing but un submit I have this error -

> Call to undefined method App\User::notify()

What i am usin in my User model:

```
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use TCG\Voyager\Contracts\User as UserContract;
use TCG\Voyager\Traits\VoyagerUser;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

class User extends Authenticatable implements UserContract
{
    use VoyagerUser;
```

Comment: `notify()` is part of the [Notifiable](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/6.x/src/Illuminate/Notifications/Notifiable.php) trait so you could try adding that in your user model traits

Comment: use on top `use Notifiable` and in `VoyagerUser` model   also use `use Notifiable`

Comment: No thats not working @Hamelraj

Comment: Do you attach this``` 'Notification' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Notification::class, `` in aliases

Comment: Have you removed this `use Notifiable;` from `User Model` ?

Answer (score 0):

Then make sure that you did following steps properly-

- Add the Notifiable train in your User model.

```
Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable
```

Add this in your app.php: For your providers:

```
Illuminate\Notifications\NotificationServiceProvider::class,
```

In the aliases:

```
'Notification' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Notification::class,
```